# Select to obtain data for each day

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that store dates in this format:

7/29/2016 00:00:00 AM

What I need is show to the user all data from one day, like

```
+-------+-------------+---------------------+
| id    | product     | date                |
+-------+-------------+---------------------+
|     1 | one         |7/27/2016 9:29:14 AM | 
|     2 | two         |7/28/2016 7:53:42 AM | 
|     3 | three       |7/28/2016 9:53:24 PM | 
+-------+-------------+---------------------+
```

So I want to return: in date 7/28/2016, 2 new products was recorded.
How can I achieve that?

This are the fields with the type of data:

```
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| product          | varchar(255)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| date             | varchar(255)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And the date was stored in DateTime format in c#. 
I've tried with between:

```
SELECT * FROM products where date between '7/29/2016 00:00:00 AM' and '7/29/2016 11:59:00 PM';
```

Doesn't work. But, when I put this:

```
SELECT * FROM products where date between '7/01/2016 00:00:00 AM' and '7/31/2016 11:59:00 PM';
```

It returns the products of the month.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What is the format of your `date` column ? Please show us the table structure, and also explain exactly what you are trying to achieve (all results grouped by date or a request on a specific date ?)

Comment: you can use Group By to achieve the results. However if you show what query you have tried so far, we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This MySQL query should work for you:

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE date >= '2016-07-28 00:00:00' AND date < '2016-07-29 00:00:00'
```

Or use [`BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between):

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-07-28 00:00:00' AND '2016-07-28 23:59:59'
```

If your date field is currently stored as a string, simply convert first with [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date, '%c/%e/%Y %h:%i:%s %p') BETWEEN '2016-07-28 00:00:00' AND '2016-07-28 23:59:59'
```

Or, if you only want a single day (And have an index on the date field), simply use [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html) syntax to utilize these indexes:

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE date LIKE '7/28/2016 %'
```

Comment: @meluluji If your date field is currently stored as a string, fix that!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name
WHERE date BETWEEN 'startdatetime' AND 'enddatetime'
```

This query may Work For you.